# Add values into numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

I am trying to create a numpy array, by adding same values, but it's something that I did wrong.
I started with simple variables, that are simple simple float numbers, just one value per variable like:

- **id**: which will be the id from my db
- **uId**: user Id
- **date**: date in milliseconds
- **time**: time in milliseconds
- **hr**: heart rate value

I defined my np array as: `dataUser = []` and I tired to use concatenate the values like this:

```
dataUser = np.concatenate((dataUser , id))
dataUser = np.concatenate(dataUser , uId)
dataUser = np.concatenate((dataUser , date))
dataUser = np.concatenate((dataUser , time))
dataUser = np.concatenate((dataUser , hr))
```

But when I run the code, I have an error:

```
all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 0 dimension(s)
```

Used `np.column_stack`, and `np.c_`, but nothing.

I tried to use append, but the result isn't something that I want.

The dataUser at **the end** Is needed to look, based on

```
[id, uId, date, time, hr]
```

something like this

```
[[1 1 1640988000000.0 16260 90]
 [2 1 1640988000000.0 16320 92]]
```

But the **append** function will give me the result like:

```
[1 1 1640988000000.0 16260 90 2 1 1640988000000.0 16320 92]
```

How can I do to have the result that I want?

Comment: You're supplying a tuple of items to concatenate. The items should all be arrays, of the same dimension. The second item, however, is a scalar, while the first item is an array. Those have different dimensions. Use append to append scalars to an array.

Comment: It is also weird that you add an id, uid, date, time, and hr to the *same* array. Because these are all very distinctive, and *different* types of data normally. A Numpy array is *not* a Python list: array elements should be of the same type.

Comment: I would not use a NumPy array for this, because these are all different types and especially because you have dates and times in there. A Pandas `DataFrame` makes a lot more sense. Pandas can give you most of the speed of NumPy, because the columns are arrays (essentially), but it's much more convenient for wrangling data like yours.

Comment: `concatenate` is best used once, with a whole list of arrays.  And you have to have a clear understanding of array shapes.  `concatenate` does not let you mix shapes (or dtypes).

Answer (score 0):

Look at your first step:

```
In [132]: dataUser = []
In [133]: np.concatenate((dataUser, 101))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [133], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 np.concatenate((dataUser, 101))

File <__array_function__ internals>:5, in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 0 dimension(s)
```

Hopefully, you read the `np.concatenate` docs (after getting error, if not before), and saw that the inputs have to have the same number of dimensions.  Do you understand `numpy` dimensions and shapes?

`np.concatenate` turns the inputs into arrays:

```
In [134]: np.array(dataUser)
Out[134]: array([], dtype=float64)    
In [135]: _.shape
Out[135]: (0,)

In [136]: np.array(1)
Out[136]: array(1)    
In [137]: _.shape
Out[137]: ()
```

Do you see that the first has 1 dimension, and the 2nd has 0?

`np.append` does let you join a list and a scalar, because it turns them to compatible arrays.

```
In [138]: np.append(dataUser, 1)
Out[138]: array([1.])
```

It is using `concatenate`, after making sure all inputs a 1d arrays.  Read its docs.  See what it says about `axis`, especially when `None`.

If you start with two (or more) lists of values:

```
In [140]: lists = [1, 1, 1640988000000.0, 16260, 90],[2, 1, 1640988000000.0, 16320, 92]

In [141]: lists
Out[141]: ([1, 1, 1640988000000.0, 16260, 90], [2, 1, 1640988000000.0, 16320, 92])
```

You can easily make an array from that:

```
In [142]: np.array(lists)
Out[142]: 
array([[1.000000e+00, 1.000000e+00, 1.640988e+12, 1.626000e+04,
        9.000000e+01],
       [2.000000e+00, 1.000000e+00, 1.640988e+12, 1.632000e+04,
        9.200000e+01]])
```

Depending on what you want to do, it may be better to stick with the lists.  At the very least don't try to create an array iteratively.  Iteration, and append, work fine with lists, not with arrays.